# Questions that attract new answers due to new expansions being released

Tags: discussion

Recently I have noticed a couple of older questions asking about cards which meet specific criteria in a game get new answers due to the game getting a regular expansion and new cards that meet the criteria. This got me to thinking how should a question be handled when the answer it is looking for can and will be expanded with each new scheduled release?

When we get a question like this should a new answer be posted when release adds new cards to the list? Or should we try and get one answer set up as a community wiki that can be edited to be a complete list and updated as new cards are added.

[Is there a card similar to Lugia from Fates Collide that targets GXs instead of EXs?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35660/is-there-a-card-similar-to-lugia-from-fates-collide-that-targets-gxs-instead-of)

[Can poison counters be removed?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/can-poison-counters-be-removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the current state of affairs, with some questions getting multiple answers over time as new cards are released, is acceptable and does not need to be changed. Asking "Is there a card that does X in game Y?" is very similar to asking "How can I do X in game Y?". It is generally considered acceptable on these sites for such questions to get multiple different answers from different people.

In the case of questions like [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/24226/list-of-blue-counterspells-that-can-be-played-for-free), where the initial answer has a list, it probably makes more sense to preserve that list and update it over time, but I think that should be considered in a case-by-case basis.

One final thing to keep in mind is that these case-by-case decisions can be updated over time as the state of a question changes. If a question gets 10 or 20 different answers each suggesting a single card, a new community wiki answer can be created to aggregate that information. So there's no real need to frontload that decision when the first answer is posted.

Comment: I do agree that I think that what we have is working, was just thinking as I did see a question with 4 answers and the most recent one was just adding a single card from the recent set. While not an issue now I was thinking that down the road it could be so why not think about it now.

Comment: I've added more information to my answer to hopefully address that concern.

Answer (score 2):

When we get a question asking for a card (or cards) that meet a specific criteria for a game that is still getting regular updates a community wiki answer should be started to compose a master list of cards that match what is being asked about. This will allow for a list to be maintained which anyone can update regardless of reputation. Having anyone being able to edit it will allow for newer users to help keep the answer updated without having to post a new answer or wait for an edit to be approved.

As a side note I think it would also be helpful to be able to have a notice on questions of this type to remind people to post the answer as a community wiki and to edit the answer instead of posting a new one when it needs to be updated.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for suggesting community wiki? In general that functionality should be avoided, and I don't think it should be suggested here without a strong reason.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I was thinking of community wiki mainly as it would make it easier for members without the edit privilege to contribute to. Also I wasn't sure how to deal with situations where an answer is greatly expanded overtime by other users and could gain a lot of votes.

Comment: I think we shouldn't get ahead of ourselves here. We've never had a situation that would play out like you describe, and I think there is good reason to believe that we never will. Most of these games only have a few new sets a year, and most sets won't have new cards with whatever specific criteria is asked for. Plus, there are better tools than community wiki, like comments and suggested edits, that don't needlessly take away someone's reputation points.