# Tags: Specific Criteria Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking questions looking for something in a game meeting certain criteria such as cards that have a specific effect how should they be tagged. The reason I am asking is because of a related question about handling questions that end up with a ever growing list of an answer because of regularly scheduled content releases.

For questions like this should a new tag be added to indicate that the answer is going to be a list of cards that meet the criteria and will change with each new release?

As a side note do we need multiple tags for different game types such as tcg and non-tcg?

[Questions that attract new answers due to new expansions being released](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/questions-that-attract-new-answers-due-to-new-expansions-being-released)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we should have a new tag for this. It doesn't really make sense to look at questions like this across games because each one is still very specific to the game. And we just don't get enough of these kinds of questions that we need to start sub-categorizing in this way.

In addition, tags should not be about the expected content or properties of any answers, just the topic of the question.